# Sort a list based on dictionary values in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary and then I have a list that contains the dictionary's keys. Is there a way to sort the list based off of the dictionaries values?

I have been trying this:

```
trial_dict = {'*':4, '-':2, '+':3, '/':5}
trial_list = ['-','-','+','/','+','-','*']
```

I went to use:

```
sorted(trial_list, key=trial_dict.values())
```

And got:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Then I went to go create a function that could be called with `trial_dict.get()`:

```
def sort_help(x):
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        for i in x:
            return x[i]

sorted(trial_list, key=trial_dict.get(sort_help(trial_dict)))
```

I don't think the `sort_help` function is having any affect on the sort though.  I'm not sure if using `trial_dict.get()` is the correct way to go about this either.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes [dict.get](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) is the correct (or at least, the simplest) way:

```
sorted(trial_list, key=trial_dict.get)
```

As Mark Amery commented, the equivalent explicit lambda:

```
sorted(trial_list, key=lambda x: trial_dict[x])
```

might be better, for at least two reasons:

1. the sort expression is visible and immediately editable
2. it doesn't suppress errors (when the list contains something that is not in the dict).

Comment: Oi, stop jumping in on the questions I'm answering and giving cleverer answers! :)

More seriously: there is one difference in behavior between thg's answer and mine. Mine will raise an exception if trial_values contains a value that is not a key of trial_dict, whereas thg's will silently sort that value to the front. Either may be appropriate depending upon context.

Comment: @thg435 I should have double checked the docs, I was clearly misunderstanding `.get`.

Comment: @MarkAmery: [You were good, kid, real good. But as long as I'm around, you'll always be second best, see?](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110475/quotes) ))

Comment: @MarkAmery: seriously, yes, the lambda gives you more control and in most cases this is what should be used.

Comment: :) Also serious: which of our approaches do you think is stylistically better here? I like the lambda for style reasons even in this case because it means you get to *see* the *expression* being sorted on (that is, trial_dict[x]) without doing any further thought; with your answer, I need to visualize the function being called to see that we're sorting on trial_dict.get(x), which requires an extra cognitive step. So I reckon I prefer my approach to yours. Whatcha think?

Comment: @MarkAmery `.get` not being explicit was where I was getting caught up, I can say.

Answer (score 8):

The key argument in the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) builtin function (or the [`sort`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) method of lists) has to be a function that maps members of the list you're sorting to the values you want to sort by. So you want this:

```
sorted(trial_list, key=lambda x: trial_dict[x])
```

Comment: I should be keeping lambda in mind for a smaller function like this.  I'm marking thg435 as answered but, this was real helpful to, I'll have to think to use the lambda for future use, thanks! :)