# Sort list of lists based on a dict values as key

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I saw this method to sort list based on dict values as key.

[Original Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987178/sort-a-list-based-on-dictionary-values-in-python)

Can we use this method to sort list of lists based on first value in each list?

```
trial_dict = {1:'ABC', 2:'PQR', 3:'DEF'}
trial_list = [['ABC','-','+','/','+','-','*'],
              ['DEF','-','+','/','+','-','*'],
              ['PQR','-','+','/','+','-','*']]
```

After sorting:

```
trial_list = [['ABC','-','+','/','+','-','*'],
              ['PQR','-','+','/','+','-','*'],
              ['DEF','-','+','/','+','-','*']]
```

Comment: Can *you* do this? Have you tried?

Comment: what if trial_dict is `{1:'ABC', 2:'ABC', 3:'ABC'}`?  Are you sure you don't want the dictionary the *other way around*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sorted()` function.

```
trial_dict = {1:'ABC', 2:'PQR', 3:'DEF'}
trial_dict_inv = {v: k for k, v in trial_dict.items()}
trial_list = [['ABC','-','+','/','+','-','*'],
          ['DEF','-','+','/','+','-','*'],
          ['PQR','-','+','/','+','-','*']]


print sorted(trial_list, key= lambda z:trial_dict_inv[z[0]])
```

Output:

> [['ABC', '-', '+', '/', '+', '-', '*'],
>   ['PQR', '-', '+', '/', '+','-', '*'],
>   ['DEF', '-', '+', '/', '+', '-', '*']]