# Sort list based on Counter values

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you sort a python list based on the values of a Counter object?

```
c = Counter({"a": 1, "b": 6, "c":19})
l = ["b", "c", "a"]

# after sorting based on counter values
l = ["c", "b", "a"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a list based on dictionary values in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987178/sort-a-list-based-on-dictionary-values-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) takes a key function like:

#### Code:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: -c[x])
```

or inplace as:

```
l.sort(key=lambda x: -c[x])
```

#### Test Code:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter({"a": 1, "b": 6, "c": 19})
l = ["b", "c", "a"]

# after sorting based on counter values
l = ["c", "b", "a"]

print(sorted(l, key=lambda x: -c[x]))
```

#### Results:

```
['c', 'b', 'a']
```

Comment: Shouldn't the result be reversed?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `sorted` you could achieve the same result using `most_common` method from Counter itself.

```
most_common = Counter({"a": 1, "b": 6, "c":19}).most_common()
```

**List comprehension:**

```
most_common = [item[0] for item in most_common]
```

**Operator:**

```
import operator

most_common = list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), most_common))
```

**Results:**

```
['c', 'b', 'a']
```